# cURL ask for password (Bash)

Tags: bash

I have this script in Bash:

```
curl -X PUT   "http://someurl/restapi/security-policies/action-policies/" -H  "accept: application/json" -u "some token" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"response-page": "page"}'
```

the script is aimed to run API using cURL with Token auth. Now the problem is when I run this script the API asks me for a password and pauses the execution for the rest of the script. Is there any way to send the password to that API?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the "style" / "prompt" output for password from this API?

Comment: Thank you Geno for your response. Sorry what did you mean ?

Comment: What is the **exact** prompt that is asking you for the password? Is that prompt from your end or the server end? If it's from the server end, what does their documentation say about password requirements and how to send the password? There isn't enough information here. We have no idea what the requirements of *someurl*'s REST API might be.

Comment: "when I run this script the API asks me for a password and pauses the execution for the rest of the script." How do they achieve this? What is the phenomenom of it?

Comment: Dear Ken, it's prompt from the server-side. This is the reference for the REST API: (https://campus.barracuda.com/product/webapplicationfirewall/api#/Action_Policy/put_security_policies__Policy_Name__action_policies__Attack_Action_Name__) I can enter the password manually but I want it to be done using the bash script.

Comment: Dear Geno, They do that from the server-side.

Comment: "Authorization (Header)", then the usage `-u "some token"` may be wrong, try using `-H "Authorization: some token"` instead?

Comment: Dear Geno, I don't think so, because thier documantation mentioned that : (https://campus.barracuda.com/product/webapplicationfirewall/api#/Action_Policy/put_security_policies__Policy_Name__action_policies__Attack_Action_Name__)

Comment: What if adding a `:` after "some token"? For example `-u "some token:"`

Comment: Dear Geno, Yes I do that but still the server-side is asking me for password.

Comment: That question again: How do they asking for your password? What is the output / prompt of that? What is the phenomenom of that? Please edit the question for appending this phenomenom.

Comment: Dear Geno, I wrote the (:) wrong but now it's work!. I'm very grateful to you. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a little strange for cURL to ask for password (like an interactive shell?), even noticed that you have already sent some token.

If it is **really** looks like an interactive shell, then you may wrap this request with [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)， for example

```
expect -c "spawn curl...; expect \"assword\"; send \"Password\r\n\"; interact"
```

But you may noticed that the `-u` parameter of `curl` is with value `<user:password>`, then you may append the password with this token, separated with a `:`.

<del>**Update**: After reading the document of that REST API, I think try using `-H "Authorization: some token"` instead of `-u "some token"`?</del>

**Update**: Does the prompt asking for password is "Enter host password for user 'some token':"? (I tried on WSL) If so, then add a `:` after the token.

Comment: It's work! , when I added (:) in the end of the token. I'm very appreciated.